# Tensor product of super vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, universal-property, supergeometry

The tensor product as well as the product in any category is determined by the corresponding limit diagram. So I should be able to find the product and tensor product in the category of super vector spaces together with grading preserving linear maps if I look at the usual diagrams. One finds the product pretty easily, by noting that the usual projection morphisms can only preserve the grading if we set $P(V,W) = (V_0\times W_0)\oplus (V_1\times W_1)$. Now I am stuck at the tensor product diagram; in particular, I do not quite know how we can get to the result that $V_1\otimes W_1$ belongs to the even component of the tensor product. Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the usual limit diagram for tensor products?

Comment: For every bilinear map $f: V\times W \rightarrow U$ there exists a unique linear map $g: V\otimes W \rightarrow U$ such that $f = g\circ \otimes$

Comment: How do you express bilinear maps in an arbitrary category?

Comment: I do not really know and I could not find any source covering that question. I hoped that maybe in this case one could just slightly vary the definition of bilinear in Vect?

Comment: @PrudiiArca I don't know about an arbitrary category, but if your  objects are sets and your morphisms are functions that preserve some structure, then you can always define a "bihomomorphism" as a function that preserves the structure in any one of its two arguments when the other is held fixed.

Comment: @Nathaniel sure. I was asking because op explicitly said that tensor products are given by a limit diagram *in any category*...

Comment: @PrudiiArca my comment was aimed primarily at being helpful to the OP, I just tagged you because you're part of the conversation. I've no idea what super vector spaces are, but there's a fair bet it's a category of the kind I described.

Comment: I got it! It can be done using the Tensor-Hom adjunction instead of the limit property...